# Octal-based number format in C

Tags: c, binary, char, int, octal

I'm having problem using int values in C that starts with zero's (like `00111001`).
I know that C compiler understand zero's in the beginning of a number as an octal number.

My question is how to disable it? I want to turn an 8 digit int into a `char array[8]`.
e.g. `01010001={'0','1','0','1','0','0','0','1'}`

Comment: Is this a binary representation? And are you allowed to store it in a string instead of an `int`?

Comment: Just replace leading zeroes with spaces in source code. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: It is not clear from the beginning of your question if you want an integer number with leading zeros - such as a binary represenation of a number in an int, or just a string representation of the number as I have answered below.  Are you wanting an actual integer or a char string?

Comment: Also, you can't disable octal literals. If you talk about parsing strings at runtime, that's possible. Please clarify the question with some example code.

Comment: Also, "8-digit integer" means integer between 10000000 and 99999999 (assuming you are talking about decimal digits). Integer 1010001 has seven digits. Again having a code snippet would easily show what you actually mean by 8 digit integer in context of C compiler.

Comment: C treats integer constants starting with `0` (and not with `0x`) as octal. There is no way to disable this feature in any C compiler I know of. You're telling us what you *don't* want; please update your question to tell us clearly what you *do* want. In particular, why is `char array[8] = { '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1' };` not a valid solution?

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, you probably have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You've assumed that disabling octal is the solution to your problem, and you're asking us how to do that. In fact, disabling octal (it's not even clear what that means) is almost certainly *not* the solution. You need to describe your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GCC, you can use binary literals.  Set the variable to 0b00111001.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html

Answer (score 0):

Surround your number with quotes:

```
char array[] = "01010001";
```

The above will make each digit a character in array that you can read as well as placing a `'\0'` character at the end so that it can be used as a C string - as per your last sentence.  Beware, the length of this string (in memory) will be 9 characters though because of this added `NUL` character.

Comment: If you want exactly 8 characters, you can write `char array[8] = "01010001";`. Of course you won't have a *string*, just an array of characters.

Comment: The truth is, I'm not sure if he wants `itoa()`, what I have here, or something completely different and he won't update the question.  Dunno.

Comment: He posted the question an hour ago, and he's new to the site. Let's give him some time.